# How to convert AST to GraphQL

Tags: graphql-tools, graphql-dotnet

We need to rename the fields in the graphQL, so we get the AST of the GraphQL firstly, and modify it as we need.
However, I can't find any solution to convert the AST back to the GraphQL.

The parser I use is "[GraphQL Dotnet Parser"](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `AstPrinter` class that can print out the `Document` or any Ast Node.

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL/Utilities/AstPrinter.cs

`AstPrinter.Print(…)`